# link that changes every 24 hours?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

So, i have a rails app that is structured like a book. There is, then, a Chapter model. The user needs to read one chapter per day.

I have a chapters index page, but i want to create a button in the app's dashboard that redirects the user to the chapter of the day directly, saving time for the user.

So, i need to create a link in the button that changes to the next chapter every 24 hours. How can i create a link that changes to the next record of a data base every 24 hours?

Comment: Does the chapters start when user create account, or for all users it is same ? Do you have only one book? Give more information please

Comment: Hi Nermin! For all users is the same thing. All of them need to read the same chapter.

Answer (score 1):

The exact answer depends on your implementation. However, here are some hints:

- if you store the starting date somewhere you can easily get the number of days between the two dates using something like:

  ```
   today = Date.today
   start_date = Book.start_date # this will depend on implementation
   @current_chapter = today - start_date + 1 # we add 1 because the first chapter is 1, not 0
  ```

  then your view can do something like `<%= link_to "Go to today's chapter", controller: :chapter, action: :show, id: @current_chapter %>`
- if the book starts at the same time for everyone you might just store that on the book object
- if the book starts for different people at different times you might already have an object that creates a relationship between Users and Books (e.g. `UserBook`). In that case you should probably create the `start_date` field here.

Answer (score 0):

I would use `Date`, as it is changing every day.

You save `date` for your first chapter, let say for the sake of the example it is

```
a = Date.new(2016, 1, 1) # January 1st 2016
b = Date.today # every day it is diferent
# b = February 4th 2016
c = (b - a).to_i # c = 34
# 34 days have passed since January 1st
# tomorow it will be 35
```

You can use `c` in your link for the record, for example

```
@chapter = Chapter.find(c)
link_to "Chapter #{c}", chapter_path(@chapter)
```